# Retrieve a file from storage starting with a String

Tags: java, android

I´m having problems trying to retrieve a single image file from a folder in Android.

The filename is "00070 bipack GV ZZZ.jpg". My code:

```
    File dirRoot = rootMicroSd(context);
    if (dirRoot == null) return "";
    File imgDir = new File(dirRoot, DefPrefsUtil.getDirImg(context) + "/");
    String referenciaCeros = "";
    for (int i = String.valueOf(referencia).length(); i < 5; i++) {
        referenciaCeros += "0";
    }
    referenciaCeros += String.valueOf(referencia); //00070 e.g.
```

Now, with that string containing "00070" my next (and I think final) step is retrieve the file in imgDir that starts with that string in my sdCard root path.

Answer (score 0):

I manage to figure out, applying a filter:

```
    File dirRoot = rootMicroSd(context);
    if (dirRoot == null) return "";
    File directorio = new File(dirRoot, DefPrefsUtil.getDirImg(context) + "/");
    String referenciaCeros = "";
    for (int i = String.valueOf(referencia).length(); i < 5; i++) {
        referenciaCeros += "0";
    }
    referenciaCeros += String.valueOf(referencia);
    final String finalReferenciaCeros = referenciaCeros;
    File[] allFiles = directorio.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            boolean valido = (name.startsWith(finalReferenciaCeros) && (name.endsWith(".jpg") || name.endsWith(".JPG")));
            return valido;
        }
    });
    if (allFiles.length == 0) return "";
    return allFiles[0].getAbsolutePath();
```

This way the list always come with my desired image or nothing, so I can display a default image in case that it comes empty ^^